# Maya 2014 Missing nHair/Assign Hair System

Tags: maya

Where can I find the `nHair` menu and the `Assign Hair` System option in `Maya 2014`? I know it should be under dynamics, yet it isn't there. I tried reseting my Maya preferences but it didn't help. This is what happens when I try to use `assign hair`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nHair menu is located under the nDynamics menu set.

The dropdown menu in the top left where it's labeled "Dynamics" has other options too, change this to nDynamics and your menu will change.

Assign hair system option is also in this same dropdown menu, this question shouldn't be posted on Stack Overflow though.